# How to load an image into a VBA form triggered from an Excel macro and draw rectangles with given dimensions?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that triggers a VBA form and displays an image as follows.

```
image1.Picture = LoadPicture('Path_to_imae').
```

Now I want to pass some dimensions from the Excel sheet to draw a rectangle around the center of the loaded image.

Is this possible using Excel VBA?
I could not find any material for it online.

Comment: The short answer YES. Please show us your code and be more explicit in your question: You want to pass some dimension to somewhere and then a rectangle needs to be drawn around the center????